# Upon installation crash, cannot close window to file bug report. How to attempt install again?

Tags: system-installation, laptop, crash

My installer crashed while installing Ubuntu on to my laptop. I received a message saying that I can file a bug report using the integrated bug reporting tool. I attempted to close the window so that the reporting tool could open, but I cannot get the window to close.

What is the next step in order to properly install the Ubuntu software?

Answer (score 0):

If the crash happens at a stage of setting "language, time zone or region", unplug the Ethernet cable to disconnect the laptop from the network/Internet. Then repeat the installation.